# ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams

Tags: android, layout

So i get this error when executing an adapter in FinderActivity.class.

```
public class FinderActivity extends ListActivity
{
    private List<String> itemsearchoptions = Arrays.asList(
            new String[]
                    {
                        "Search Service Center","Search Showroom",
                        "Area Surveillance", "Nearest OAC Offices"
                    });
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.finder);


        getListView().setAdapter(new FinderListAdapter(this, this.itemsearchoptions));//cause of error


    }
```

Here is My FinderAdapterclass:

```
public class FinderListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private int[]icons = 
    {
        R.drawable.icon_service_center,
        R.drawable.icon_car_showroom, 
        R.drawable.icon_radar, 
        R.drawable.icon_office
    };
    private List<String>options = null;

    public FinderListAdapter(Context paramContext, List<String>paramList)
    {
        this.context = paramContext;
        this.options = paramList;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(paramContext);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return this.options.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int paramInt) 
    {
        return this.options.get(paramInt);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int paramInt) 
    {
        return paramInt;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int paramInt, View paramView, ViewGroup paramViewGroup) 
    {
        String str = (String)this.options.get(paramInt);

        if(paramView == null)
        {

        }
        else
        {

            return paramView;
        }
        return paramViewGroup;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return (this.options == null)||(this.options.size()==0);
    }

    private static class ViewHolder
    {
        ImageView finderIcon;
        TextView finderText;
    }
}
```

I used LinearLayout on the item list

I have read several similar problems about this error, but yet to fully understand the concept. So any help will be appreciated. thanks

edited : sorry forgot the stacktrace

```
07-08 15:31:42.380: E/AndroidRuntime(4550): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 15:31:42.380: E/AndroidRuntime(4550): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
07-08 15:31:42.380: E/AndroidRuntime(4550):     at android.widget.ListView.measureScrapChild(ListView.java:1166)
07-08 15:31:42.380: E/AndroidRuntime(4550):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1248)
07-08 15:31:42.380: E/AndroidRuntime(4550):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1158)
07-08 15:31:42.380: E/AndroidRuntime(4550):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15525)
07-08 15:31:42.380: E/AndroidRuntime(4550):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
07-08 15:31:42.380: E/AndroidRuntime(4550):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
07-08 15:31:42.380: E/AndroidRuntime(4550):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
07-08 15:31:42.380: E/AndroidRuntime(4550):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
07-08 15:31:42.380: E/AndroidRuntime(4550):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15525)
07-08 15:31:42.380: E/AndroidRuntime(4550):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
07-08 15:31:42.380: E/AndroidRuntime(4550):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-08 15:31:42.380: E/AndroidRuntime(4550):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15525)
07-08 15:31:42.380: E/AndroidRuntime(4550):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
```

Comment: post your stacktrace also...

Comment: check your imported classes

Comment: BTW: to me your `getView()` makes no sense.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `android.widget.AbsListView.LayoutParams` instead of the `android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams` in your imports.

A ClassCastException stacktrace is pretty descriptive...

Comment: solved. seems that i misplaced few codes. thanks for answering dou

Comment: can you help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30951608/java-lang-classcastexception-android-view-viewgrouplayoutparams-cannot-be-cast

Answer (score 1):

For the rest of you which have the same problem. Please at first, fix your getView method.

Try to make it like this.

```
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View root;

    if(view == null){
       root = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayout, null);
    } else {
       root = view;
    }

    return root;
    }
```

This may solve the `android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams` error.

Trust me, I just facing this exact problem, but I manage to solve it this way.