# ClassCastException when trying to add a footer to a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, classcastexception

I'm trying to add a footer to a `ListView`, and I'm getting the following error:

```
06-30 03:57:27.545: E/AndroidRuntime(10112): java.lang.ClassCastException: 
android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to 
android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
```

Here is my ListView's footer (listview_footer.xml):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="7dip"
    android:paddingBottom="7dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/addButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/add_button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the code that I'm using to add the footer to the ListView:

```
View footerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_footer, null, false);  

addButton = (ImageButton) footerView.findViewById(R.id.addButton);

listView.addFooterView(footerView);
```

And on this line:

```
View footerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_footer, null, false);
```

the "null" argument is showing up with an orange line beneath it in Eclipse, and when I hover over it, it says:

```
Avoid passing null as the view root (needed to resolve layout 
parameters on the inflated layout's root element)
```

In this situation, I'm not sure what I should specify as the second argument (ViewGroup root).

Comment: are you setting programmatically the LayoutParams to addButton ?

Comment: No, I'm setting them in the footer xml file I posted above.

Comment: the snippet looks good. Have you tried to clean and rebuild the project ?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse, so I have to clean and rebuild about 1000x/day :) But yeah, I just tried cleaning/rebuilding and it's the same error.

Comment: can you tried to call `footerView.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(ListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));` before calling addFooterView ?

Comment: Why do you think the problem is in that line? The stacktrace should point to the exact line number. Look further down the stacktrace instead of only those 3 lines. Could you post the entire stacktrace?

Comment: I already tried that and it was giving me the same error.

Comment: Added the stacktrace and a comment about why I think it's that line.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to replace

`View footerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_footer, null, false);`

with

`View footerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_footer, listview, false);`

That way the inflater will give it the right layoutparams

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that and it gave me the same error.

Answer (score -1):

Use `android.widget.AbsListView.LayoutParams instead of the android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams` in your imports.

A ClassCastException stacktrace is pretty descriptive...

Comment: But I'm not importing anything like that in my imports.

Comment: Nice copy work from http://stackoverflow.com/a/17523506/1554935, you could have posted the link in comment.