# Getting ClassCast Exception on API 19 but working fine on API 21

Tags: android, eclipse, navigation-drawer, material-design

I have implemented a `material design navigation drawer` and a `custom toolbar`. It works perfectly fine on `Lollipop` device.

But when run on `Android 4.4.4, it crashes` with error mentioned below :

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams
>   cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams

I have not changed any layout of navigation drawer. Code sample to set up drawer :

```
mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_drawer);

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setup(R.id.fragment_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer), mToolbar);
```

**LogCat :**

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
            at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1826)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1793)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2087)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14857)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14857)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14857)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:907)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14857)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14857)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14857)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14857)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14857)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14857)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14857)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2013)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1770)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1019)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5725)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Somewhere in your code you are using LayoutParams that are of the wrong type.

Comment: Couldnt locate that somewhere because its working on API 21 !

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045198/android-view-viewgrouplayoutparams-cannot-be-cast-to-android-widget-abslistview or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17523256/classcastexception-android-widget-linearlayoutlayoutparams to see the meaning of your exception

Answer (score 3):

Android has made major changes in AppCompat v21.

So, please refer to this link:
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same problem.I used a Adapter for GridView.This error happens when i set LayoutParams of a LinearLayout inside of getView() method. I solved this using this code

```
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

instead of

```
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and use AppCompatv21 .May be then error will not come as Material design will be compatible for prelollipop versions with this AppCompat.

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Comment: I am using app compat v7 in Eclipse and appcompat 21 in android studio. But not working